# Mod articles archived override not working?

Tags: module, articles, overrides, template-override

I am using Joomla 3.8.0, and I have made an override for the mod_articles_archived module. For some reason it doesnt read the override? I have the following map structure now:

templates/mytemplate/html/mod_articles_archive/helper.php

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot override a module's `helper.php` file. You can only override the view (`mod_articles_archive/tmpl/default.php`). What exactly are you wanting to change in the helper? If you let us know, perhaps we can help come to another solution.

Comment: I am trying to change the query in the helper.php, because I have a menu that is build up by the dates of archived articles. But it shows the month and the year, and I want it to only show the years. Now is is like:

may - 2007
april - 2007
may - 2006
june - 2008

and I want it:

2008
2007
2006

But the weird part is, when I made an override through Joomla, it made the helper.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah right, now that I know what you wish to achieve, this is a very simple task that doesn't require any code changes :)

This text you want to change derives from a language string:

> MOD_ARTICLES_ARCHIVE_DATE="%1$s, %2$s"

Where `%1$s` is the month, and `%2$s` is the year.

---

#### Solution:

In you Joomla backend, go to: **Extensions** >> **Language** >> **Overrides** >> **New**

In the **Language Constant** field, add `MOD_ARTICLES_ARCHIVE_DATE`

In the **Value** field, add `%2$s`

---

#### Screenshot:

[image]

---

#### Result:

[image]

---

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, but I need to combine the months from a whole year in to one year in one menu item, so you can click on a year and then you will get all articles from that year. This means that I need to also change the link that is created in helper.php and also the query, because the list is created by the amount of rows, so if I remove the monts in the query, I am only getting the years, and that is what I want. Sorry for my very very vague question.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to do that?

Comment: @Brum - Perhaps take a copy of the module, change the name and class, then install it. You can then change the helper.php file as if it were your own module. Other than that, there may be some way to extend the class, however I'm not a PHP developer so wouldn't be the best person to ask. Or you can check the Joola Extensions Directory to see if any archiving extensions exist.